# SSLRead() error using Git in Mavericks OS X 10.9.2

Tags: git, ssl, osx-mavericks

Since I installed Git through Xcode-tools in my MBP with Mavericks OS X 10.9.2. I am not able to clone a existing repo into my computer. I'm pretty sure that the problem is in my current computer, because the repo works fine from other PCs.

The error is:

> amoreno$ git clone https://git.cen*********14.git/
>   Cloning into 'ttc14'...
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://git.cen*****14.git/': SSLRead() return error -9841

I have ruled out completely problems with the SSL certificate, since the global config is:

> [http]
>        sslVerify = false

I have both versions Git 1.8.5.2 (installed with Xcode) and Git 1.9.0 (installed using the real git installer), and the same message is returned.

Comment: If someone has the same problem, it could be solved downloading the SSL certificate from the repo server. Once it has been installed in your Keychain, git will work in complete normalcy.

Comment: where do I find the SSL certificate for the github repo (to put it into my Keychain)?  I do not see any "DigiCert High Assurance CA-*" certificates (as mentioned in one of the answers here)

Answer (score 1):

found this page. thanks author.

http://stuffandymakes.com/2014/03/11/os-x-mavericks-10-9-2-causes-ssl-errors-git-bitbucket/

Open KeyChain app, delete "DigiCert High Assurance CA-*" certificates, then reboot your mac.

Comment: I have the same error (* SSLRead() return error -363/5662), 759.39 MiB | 59.00 KiB/s  /  * Closing connection 0  /  error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200). this did not work for me, as there was no "DigiCert High Assurance CA-*" certificates in my keychain.