# Can't clone own github repository, get obscure fatal error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssl, github, git-clone

So I made changes to my rails app on my local machine that were never committed and that I decided to discard. Decided to rollback to most recent commit by deleting my rails app and all its files, and then cloning my most recent commit from my github repository. Unfortunately

```
git clone https://github.com/my_username/rails_app.git
```

results in the following error that cannot be found by just googling:

```
Cloning into 'sample_app2'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/IPX-/sample_app2.git/': SSLRead() return error -9806
```

I was recently pushing to the repo earlier today, even set up an SSH key for my this laptop, but all to no avail.

Why is git clone not working for my own repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible error due to low internet connection. This error occurred when you try to connect to server through ssl and net connection drop immediately. Or some time due to frequent disconnection. YOu can find more about this here http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.in/2014/04/sslread-return-error-9806-server.html

Comment: University internet can be spotty at times, and when I tried to load a treehouse video it took about 10 seconds to load about 1 second of video. Closed terminal and reopened it this morning(was having the trouble last night) and git clone worked just fine. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [SSLRead() error using Git in Mavericks OS X 10.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492987/sslread-error-using-git-in-mavericks-os-x-10-9-2)

Anyhow, the answer mentioned here is that you download SSL and install.

When you have already set up SSH then why don't you access your repo over SSH?

You can use `user.name@github.com:<your-repo>` and it will not ask you for password if you have actually set-up SSH properly!

Enjoy!