# SSLRead() return error -9806/15958)

Tags: git

When I try cloning [this](https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca) repo (link only works when git cloning) I keep getting `error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200`. How would I fix this? I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197171/git-clone-repository-error-rpc-failed-result-56-http-code-200) post that tells me to use `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1` to debug it however I cannot see any issues right away.

Here is my log.

```
Folder=OneDrive;-time=14:41:47: GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://git01.codeplex.com/casablanca
Cloning into 'casablanca'...
* Couldn't find host git01.codeplex.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.96.195.41...
* Connected to git01.codeplex.com (23.96.195.41) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.codeplex.com
* Server certificate: MSIT Machine Auth CA 2
* Server certificate: Microsoft Internet Authority
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> GET /casablanca/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/2.3.1
Host: git01.codeplex.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:41:52 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 1296
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Couldn't find host git01.codeplex.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.96.195.41...
* Connected to git01.codeplex.com (23.96.195.41) port 443 (#1)
* SSL re-using session ID
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.codeplex.com
* Server certificate: MSIT Machine Auth CA 2
* Server certificate: Microsoft Internet Authority
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> POST /casablanca/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/2.3.1
Host: git01.codeplex.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request
Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
Content-Length: 890

* upload completely sent off: 890 out of 890 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Sun, 08 Mar 2015 14:41:58 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
remote: Counting objects: 15958, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7214/7214), done.
* SSLRead() return error -9806/15958), 3.93 MiB | 462.00 KiB/s      
* Closing connection 1
remote: Total 15958 (delta 11496), reused 12082 (delta 8470)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
Receiving objects: 100% (15958/15958), 4.12 MiB | 479.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (11496/11496), done.
Folder=OneDrive;-time=14:42:09: ls
Folder=OneDrive;-time=14:42:11:
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22492987/sslread-error-using-git-in-mavericks-os-x-10-9-2) to fix it but it does not work.

I have also tried updating git via home brew. My git version is `git version 2.3.1`

If you need to know this is on Yosemite. I also have no anti-virus.

**Note**

`Folder=OneDrive;-time=14:41:47:` is the bash prompt (I changed it).

Comment: Warning: broken links.

Comment: That 'broken' link only works when doing git clone. You cannot view it in the web browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error)

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you link git against GnuTLS, you have to explicitly link it against OpenSSL. CodePlex has a [support page](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Git%20HTTPS%20cloning%20errors) about this issue.

Comment: I am on Mac OS X Yosemite and do not have `apt-get` as a result of that. I did however install git from home brew like I have said. Thanks for looking into the problem though. Would brew update work the same way?

Comment: Instead of homebrew I would suggest using the official git binary from http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: So would I then put the executable in a folder such as ~/bin and set the path variable to ~/bin:$PATH?

Comment: Sadly its been a long time I used OSX, you have to check the relevant documents. But what you said sounds plausible, yes.