# Stack Build error message: exited with ExitFailure 128

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm following chapter 13.3 of *"Haskell Programming from First Principles"* 
 and working on `stack build` but fail with below error message as below. I'm doing on my MBP terminal with *current Stack version: 1.3.2* installed, . Any solution for a way out? (I'm currently working with very slow wifi environment. I'm not sure whether stack build fails because of bad connectivity.)

```
$ stack build
Updating package index Hackage (mirrored at 
https://github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes.git) ...
```

Long Pause Here... almost 10 minutes.

```
Running /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes.git all-cabal-hashes/ -b display in directory /Users/Sleepyleo/.stack/indices/Hackage/git-update/ exited with ExitFailure 128

Cloning into 'all-cabal-hashes'...  
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: "I'm currently working with very slow wifi environment. I'm not sure whether stack build fails because of bad connectivity." -- Sounds plausible, though it is hard to tell for sure. This specific step (updating the package index) shouldn't be taking so long. Did you get to run `stack build` successfully in your system in the past?

Comment: It's my first try using *stack build*. I've installed stack 3.1.2 like a 3-4 months back and never have run it. I'm trying to `stack upgrade` now but slow wifi here make me impatient.

Comment: FWIW on my machine `./.stack/indices/Hackage/git-update/all-cabal-hashes` is ~ 250 MB so that can take a while to fully clone on a slow connection.

Comment: 250MB is pretty huge. This cloning need to be done every time running `stack build`? or only one time at the very first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code -9806 is a Mac OS X error code for a generic SSL connection failure.  Others have reported this as a problem with older versions of `git` connecting to certain sites with incompatible SSL configurations.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927901/sslread-return-error-9806-15958), for example.  However, it's also been reported as a result of a connection being interrupted on a flaky Internet connection (e.g., [this github issue](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15969)).

Unfortunately, since you are seeing this after a 10 minute timeout, it's likely your Internet connection rather than an SSL compatibility problem.

You might want to try running:

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/commercialhaskell/all-cabal-hashes.git
    all-cabal-hashes/ -b display
```

manually in a directory somewhere.  It's about a 200 megabyte download.  This will show you if it's making any progress and how fast the download is running.

Comment: thank you very much Mr. Buhr. It doesn't solve my problem but at least I know what my problem is. Really thanks.